# Django Forms ChoiceField is not showing options; remains hidden

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

views.py

```
def rank(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RankRegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid:
        form.user = request.user
        form.save(commit=False)
        return redirect('matches/rank.html')
else:
    form = RankRegisterForm()

return render(request, 'matches/rank.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class RankRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

rank = forms.ChoiceField(choices=rankChoices)
class Meta:
    model = Rank
    fields = (
        "rank",
    )
```

html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="container">
        <p> Belt Rank Status </p>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button  class="red-text text-darken-1" type="submit">Submit</button>
            <br></br>
        </form>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
class Rank(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(
    CustomUser,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    primary_key=True,
)


rank = models.CharField("rank", max_length=20, choices=rankChoices)
rankPoints = models.IntegerField("rank points", default=0)
certificateOfLegitimacy = models.BooleanField(default=False)
promoted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.rank + ", " + self.user.email
```

DOM

```
<form method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="ITC0cjPUCmvhuYD2K1eDgjPOt1daSRJbi8mbpLmv6ETGVe9akMI2SOfjEJQcXJ9A">
        <p>
<label for="id_rank">Rank:</label>
<select name="rank" id="id_rank">
```

White
  Blue
  Purple
  Brown
  Black

thanks, this sucks. I've been looking everywhere and there isn't a question related to mine that has been answered. It's hidden, i suspect it's because of the csrf shit. but idk. help a brother out.

Comment: Where is this **rankChoices** ? Can you show the value of this variable

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try indenting the `Meta` class and `rank` variable into the `RankRegisterForm` class

```
   #forms.py
    class RankRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
        rank = forms.ChoiceField(choices=rankChoices)
        class Meta:
            model = Rank
            fields = (
                "rank",
            )
```